# Can't unvote accidental election vote?

Tags: support, election

Due to an occasional goofy issue in how my browser loads some pages, I accidentally cast a vote in moderator election.

Is there a way to undo it? I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to revoke your vote.  However, you may change your vote at any time until the election is over.   Simply visit the [election page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election) and select a different first choice candidate.